# Search for name in one sheet, copy, paste in another sheet and insert new row on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling quite a while with possible solutions, but i couldn't find something similar online, and im could use some help.
Screenshot example and workbook sample in links under question.
I asked same question on different forum, but no answers... https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/find-copy-insert-row-on-condition-with-cell-merge-and-formula-copy.1178634/

I have 3 worksheets, `ForDelivery`, `Document1` and `Document2`. From document sheets i print first page or  send it via email, i want to fill specific cells in document sheets 1 and 2 (`range"G19:K"`) with values from `ForDelivery` sheets (values are in range`"B2:F"`.

In sheets `Document1` and `Document2` i have table template, column "B" in both sheets contain product names, i would need macro that would search for those names in sheet `ForDelivery` and if name is found in column `"A"` then copy all values from range `"B:F"` from row where name was found into row in sheet where name is, column range `"G:K"`. I menage to complete this job with `XLOOKUP fuction` BUT problem happends when there is more then one product name in column `"A"` (number can vary from 2 to 8). That function can't handle, but i hope macro can. So for every same name i need to insert new row under orginal row, copy forumlas from above, and paste values to range `"G:K"`. I made a code that will merge cells in columns `A`,`B`, and `F`, to prevent duplicates values. So basically, if there are 3 same names in column `"A"` in `ForDelivery` sheet insert 2 row (2 because there is already one row existing) in `Document 1 or 2` sheet where name is found, and paste data from range `B:F` into range `G:K`. Thanks in advance.

ScreenShot: https://ibb.co/sFh5dRY
Workbook sample here: https://easyupload.io/4f7cq2

If its of some use, here is the code i use for merging cells in columns

```
Sub macro1()
Dim lngLastRow As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastcolumn As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveSheet.Sort
.SetRange Range(Cells(19, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastcolumn))
.Header = xlYes
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With

For i = lastRow To 19 Step -1

If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).Select
Selection.Merge
Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i - 1, 2)).Select
Selection.Merge
Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i - 1, 3)).Select
Selection.Merge
Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i - 1, 6)).Select
Selection.Merge

End If

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, I added comments so you can have an idea what's going on.
Codename is given inside VBA for any sheet, they are good if your sheets will not be deleted by anyone. If not change them to your sheet names as usual.

Note: I can't seem to see the comments in a different color in the preview. Also, didn't test the formula part. Sorry if I missed something.

```
Public Sub Populate_Document1()
    
    Dim i As Long, no_item_doc1 As Long, currentrow_doc1 As Long
    Dim rngDelivery As Range
    Dim cCell_Doc1 As Range
    Dim cCell_Delivery As Range
    
    Dim rngDoc1 As Range
    Dim arrDoc1 As Variant
    Dim lastrow_doc1 As Long
    
    ' Find last row of Document1 (Codename set as doc1 in VBA Editor)
    ' doc1 = sheets("Document1")
    ' delivery = sheets("ForDelivery")
    lastrow_doc1 = doc1.Cells(18, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    
    Set rngDoc1 = doc1.Range("B19:B" & lastrow_doc1)
    
    ' Assign rngDoc1 values to an array arrDoc1
    ReDim arrDoc1(1 To rngDoc1.Rows.Count, 1 To 1) As String
    arrDoc1 = rngDoc1.Value ' arrays normally start with index 0, but 1 if we assign from a range
    
    ' Set rngDelivery to items list on ForDelivery Sheet
    ' Can be done in one line, but easier to read like this
    Set rngDelivery = delivery.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngDelivery = rngDelivery.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDelivery.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    
    currentrow_doc1 = 19 ' will update this if we insert any lines due to duplicates
    
    For i = 19 To lastrow_doc1
        no_item_doc1 = 0 ' reset to 0, number of items found on delivery sheet for the item in question in doc1
        For Each cCell_Delivery In rngDelivery
            If cCell_Delivery.Value = arrDoc1(i - 18, 1) Then
                If no_item_doc1 = 0 Then
                    no_item_doc1 = 1
                    cCell_Delivery.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy doc1.Range("G" & currentrow_doc1)
                Else
                    ' increase currentrow since a duplicate is found
                    currentrow_doc1 = currentrow_doc1 + 1
                    
                    ' Insert a row
                    doc1.Rows(currentrow_doc1).Insert
                    
                    ' copy the B-F columns from delivery sheet
                    cCell_Delivery.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 5).Copy doc1.Range("G" & currentrow_doc1)
                    
                    ' copy A-F columns of duplicate item from 1 row above
                    doc1.Range("A" & currentrow_doc1 - 1 & ":F" & currentrow_doc1 - 1).Copy doc1.Range("A" & currentrow_doc1 & ":F" & currentrow_doc1)
                    
                    ' copy the formulas from 1 row above
                    doc1.Range("D" & currentrow_doc1 - 1 & ":E" & currentrow_doc1 - 1).Copy
                    doc1.Range("D" & currentrow_doc1 & ":E" & currentrow_doc1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    
                    ' set font color to easily distinguish duplicates, can remove later if you want
                    doc1.Range("A" & currentrow_doc1 & ":F" & currentrow_doc1).Font.Color = rgbRed
                End If
            End If
        Next cCell_Delivery
        
        ' increase currentrow by 1 since we are moving on to the next item on doc1
        currentrow_doc1 = currentrow_doc1 + 1
    Next i
    
    ' clean up set objects, not necessary here but good practice
    Set rngDoc1 = Nothing
    Set rngDelivery = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for late  response. code workst perfect. I just declared worksheets, and duplicated code for document2.  Great job man, i owe you.  But i just noticed while testing, there is a little problem, i would be even better i code can be adjusted copy some other formulas in rows.  I created this template to shift formulas down while i copy and insert new row. Other formulas are in range for each row  where names are in column range "O:AF".  Can i add lines in code simmilar to original formula copy in D and E columns?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean exactly. Are these formulas in the original sample workbook? However, you can do many things, I just need to know exactly what is needed. You can enter a formula to a cell/range of cells using VBA of course. Or copy from somewhere else if needed.

Comment: Here is the link for complete document with your module and some mine that i created are in workbook https://easyupload.io/skxfgi 
Sorry for not putting whole thing in first sample... i thought it woudn t need... 
when u copy for example row 20 and insert it in row 21, formulas from that row in column D and E in document and in table right from document are moved down to new row, so that sum function can work...

Comment: Screenshot: https://ibb.co/DtpXv2H
Explanation:  formula from "O19" need to be copied in new row in picture in O20 (formula in cell O19 is (=D19)  and so on  until last name in column B.  i need those formulas to count number of boxes for each product when i insert new row. I don t know the other way... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for late response also. I have been tired the last two days. Let's go from an example. For item "1" (line 19). What would you want the formulas be? Include both ranges (D:E) and O+. If the formulas on D:E are correct for the added item (second "1") on line 20, you just need to copy the formulas the same way as we did for D:E. Also, what happens if you run the macro a second time, say, by mistake? It will be a mess :)

Comment: Hi, no problem with that :D .Only problem here is that i don t know the other way to sum values in column D for one name from colum B when i merge cells.  So if i have for item (1) two new rows (added items)  i can t apply SumIF when i merge names in column B, only first value is shown by function.  That works, when i link first value in D19, by entering =D19 in cell O19, and when i insert new row that link move down and in the end i sum all linked cells and get wanted result and by the same way is done for all items in column B.  I limmited  macro to run only one time on command button :)

Comment: Completed.  i just copied your original line of code, and pasted it belove , changed range from D : E, to O : AF, and its working as expected. Sorry for bothering :D

Comment: Good to hear :) Every problem you face will make you better.